# HTML5 --> where to start?! (compatibility with older)

Tags: html, compatibility

I am aware of the great, wide new spectre of possibilities, but I have
almost no clue about Html5.

As one of the (from many) way to exponentially send back IE6 to the Big-Bang era - is to massively accept new technologies and methods... Well let's go with HTML5. How to embrace it in the meaning of compatibility without spending 70%+ time we usually spent looking at a Microsoft product.

Let's say we decide to start our new project in HTML5, what are the best practicies, problematics, links, infos... all related with older browsers compatib..

Do we have to create html5 docs apart or are they handable and how by oldyes.

Any good link or suggestion or explanation?

Comment: Computers with IE6 no longer exist. Well they do, on unused lab computers that haven't been updated in 10 years and have 100 viruses. In order to embrace HTML5, you probably will want to ignore the browsers that do not support it.

Comment: @ninja - haha ofcourse! I'm the first to agree. I was just comparing - and asking my self... is now html5 (till it becomes fully supported) a mean-time-new-evil! Hehehe ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for a massive amount of information here...

What I would suggest is to visit a site such as [net.tutsplus.com](http://net.tutsplus.com/) and do a search for html5. I would also get acquainted with the [html5 shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) and other techniques to provide cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Exactly... I was looking for just something like this! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I started with [html5boilerplate](http://www.html5boilerplate.com) - it's a great way to begin

If you can afford a book, I'd recommend [hard boiled webdesign](http://hardboiledwebdesign.com/) by Andy Clarke

good luck

Answer (score 1):

The rules for using features added in HTML 5 are the same as those we have been following for the past decade. Use [progressive enhancement](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) as normal.